# ListBox gets only 8 items from ItemSource

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm developing the app on Windows phone.
On View i have Grid with ListBox:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox x:Name="TestListbox" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding History}"                    
                Margin="24,0"   
                SelectionChanged="GoToSelection" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HistoryDataTemplate}"
                >

            </ListBox>            
        </Grid>
```

History is ObservableCollection.

And HistoryDataTemplate looks like:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HistoryDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <HistoryControls:HistoryItem d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Margin="0,0,0,24"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

i use constructor of  HistoryItem for subscribing to PropertyChanged event:

```
     public HistoryItem()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                base.Loaded+=(new RoutedEventHandler(this.HistoryControl_Loaded));
            }
 private void HistoryControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._dataContext.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this._dataContext_PropertyChanged);
        }
```

When i have 1-8 items all works correct, but for >8 items  constuctor is called only 8 times.

Comment: If there are only 8 items visible on the screen it's probably virtualizing them, the constructor would only get called after that as you scroll new items on to the display.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Can i change this behavior and call ctor for all items in one time?

Comment: You would need to disable virtualization.

Answer (score 4):

If there are only 8 items visible on the form then the constructor isn't being called for off screen items because the list is virtualizing them.

you can change this behaviour with the property

```
 <ListBox x:Name="TestListbox" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

Comment: I have changed my View to:  <ListBox x:Name="QRHistoryListbox" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" but right now i have XamlParseException:Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing' threw an exception. [Line: 38 Position: 48]

Answer (score 1):

I added ListBox.ItemsPanel and it helps.
More info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oren/archive/2010/11/08/wp7-silverlight-perf-demo-1-virtualizingstackpanel-vs-stackpanel-as-a-listbox-itemspanel.aspx